# How to pass multiple values of a textbox from one form to another form in access

Tags: ms-access

I have two forms for Purchase and Sales in my inventory DB. Sometimes I need to show a purchase to sale directly in the purchase form. I have seen other questions like this which couldn't solve my problems. Also I tried like the following:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command25_Click()
    MsgBox "Are you sure to show this purchase as direct sale?", vbYesNo, "Direct Sale"
    If vbYes Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "SF02PurchasetoSale", acNormal, , , , , DirectSale
           
    End If
       
End Sub

Private Sub DirectSale()
    Forms![SF02PurchasetoSale].[TxnDate] = Me.TxnDate.Value
    Forms![SF02PurchasetoSale].[Hub] = Me.Hub.Value
    Forms![SF02PurchasetoSale].[Code] = Me.Code.Value
    Forms![SF02PurchasetoSale].[PurchasePrice] = Me.PurchasePrice.Value
    Forms![SF02PurchasetoSale].[QtySold] = Me.QuantityPurchased.Value
    
End Sub
```

This shows the "compile error: Expected Function or variable" on the openargs of DirectSale. I really need some help here. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenArgs is to pass values to form or report specified in OpenForm or OpenReport command. Consider:

`DoCmd.OpenForm "SF02PurchasetoSale", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, , "DirectSale"`

Then code behind SF02PurchasetoSale:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
With Me
If .OpenArgs = "DirectSale" Then
    .[TxnDate] = Forms!Purchases.TxnDate
    .[Hub] = Forms!Purchases.Hub
    .[Code] = Forms!Purchases.Code
    .[PurchasePrice] = Forms!Purchases.PurchasePrice
    .[QtySold] = Forms!Purchases.QuantityPurchased
End If
End With
End Sub
```